# Usernames not getting saved on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise to manager users and i'm getting a strange error. I have the categories of email, username, and password on my signup page, the email and password get passed to the database just fine but i can't get the username to save there. If i edit the user after signup, the username displays just fine.

Here is my signup page code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1>Sign up</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Continue" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-footer">
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am i missing putting in username somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
```

to my applications controller